# How can I call fetch function from action file in componentDidMount() component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I was fetching data using `onclick` button but now I want to fetch on page load using `componentDidMount()`.

My fetch function is under action file and I am using react native with redux.
My function name is `submitToServer(){}`. How can I call it on `componentDidMount`?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you use Redux when you dont even know the basic patterns of React?

Comment: You can call it in `componentDidMount` the same way you're calling it on the `onClick` event. Given the information you've given us this is all I can say

Comment: apokryfos, yeah brother, it's done now, there was just missing something like this.props.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // here you fetch your data
    submitToServer();
  }

  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The `submitToServer()` call will then trigger some Redux store changes, which the react-redux library will process and trigger a properties change event in your `SomeComponent` component (if `connect`ed, of course). Then, your component will be re-rendered, and you would be able to use the retreived data.